# Iterating through an Ember Object

Tags: ember.js

I have Ember.Object which is being used as a basic key/value dictionary. The names of the keys are dynamic and what I'd like to be able do is iterate over these properties. Seems like this should be easy but google searches and my collective head scratching doesn't seem to point to the obvious answer I was expecting.

For the following psuedo code:

```
App.MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
    randomComputedProperty: function() {
        return "foobar";
    }     
}
$object = new MyObject.create(someBigAndUnpredictableNameValueHash);
```

My ideal solution would solve for this code would allow me to quickly discern:

- Critically: an array of property names that that `object` has
- Ideally: an array of computed property names that `object` has
- Icing-on-the-Top: an array of computed properties that include setters along getter

Anyway have any ideas?

----- UPDATE -----

To be a little more explicit about my precise use case. The fictional `MyObject` is actually a property that comes in from one my models:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
    prop1: DS.attr('string'),
    prop2: DS.attr('number'),
    prop3: DS.attr('my-object')
}
```

Where a Transform object is setup to handle serialization/deserialization:

```
App.MyObjectTransform = DS.Trnasform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return App.MyObject.create(serialized)
    },
    deserialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
}
```

This way when I'm working with `MyModel` in a handlebars template I can do something like:

```
{{prop1}}
{{prop2}}
{{#each prop3}}
    {{key}} = {{value}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Ember **v2.0.0-beta.1** [you can use](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_each-in-helper) `{{each-in}}` helper, which lets you to iterate over object keys and their values in your templates.

For example, sample object:

```
App.MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  randomComputedProperty() {
    return 'foobar';
  }     
});
```

Instantiated this way:

```
let $object = App.MyObject.create({
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: ['element1', 'element2']
});
```

And iterated over in template using `{{each-in}}` helper:

```
{{#each-in $object as |key value|}}
  `{{key}}`:`{{value}}`
{{/each-in}}
```

Produces following results:

```
`prop1`:`value1`
`prop2`:`value2`
`prop3`:`element1,element2`
```

[JSBin demonstrating this.](http://jsbin.com/rusevogeda/2/)

It's worth to mention that using `{{each-in}}` helper:

> is a one time snapshot look at the object, it will not observe
>   properties being added/removed/changed.

Thanks @Kingpin2k for pointing this out. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/dijidilela/2/edit?html,js,output), note that update to `prop1` isn't reflected in the DOM.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is a one time snapshot look at the object, it will not observe properties being added/removed/changed.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some ideas.

**Object's Keys method 1**

You can iterate over the properties and filter out the keys from the prototype chain (using [the `hasOwnProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)):

```
var obj = App.MyObject.create({stuff: "stuff!"});

var objKeys = []
for(var key in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    objKeys.push(key);
  }
}
console.log(objKeys); // ['stuff']
```

**Object's Keys method 2**

On newer browsers you can directly get an array of the object's properties using [the `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ['stuff']
```

**Ember.Object's computed properties**

Ember provides a way to iterate over the computed properties of a class using the [`eachComputedProperty()` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_eachComputedProperty)

```
App.MyObject.eachComputedProperty(function(name, meta){
  console.log(name, meta);  // randomComputedProperty
});
```

[JSBin example demonstrating these methods](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1473/edit)

**Update**

You could have a computed property on your model that re-arranges the `MyObject`'s data into an array which can then be displayed by handlebars:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  prop1: DS.attr('string'),
  prop2: DS.attr('number'),
  prop3: DS.attr('my-object'),

  prop3PropertyArray: function(){
    var prop3, 
        propertyArray = [];

    prop3 = this.get('prop3');

    for(var key in prop3) {
      if(prop3.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== "toString"){
        propertyArray.push({key: key, value: prop3.get(key)});
      }
    }

    return propertyArray;
  }.property('prop3')
});
```

If `prop3` contained:

```
prop3: App.MyObject.create({
  stuff: "stuff!",
  anotherRandomKey: "more value here"
})
```

then `prop3PropertyArray` would be:

```
[
  {
    key: "stuff",
    value: "stuff!"
  },
  {
    key: "anotherRandomKey",
    value: "more value here"
  }
]
```

which can then be displayed in handlebars using an `{{#each}}..{{/each}}` helper:

```
{{#each item in prop3PropertyArray}}
  {{item.key}} = {{item.value}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

[Updated JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1482/edit)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll look into these. What do you think about just switching away from an EmberObject into some Enumerable type? Wouldn't this help me iterate through the collection in a handlebars template.

Comment: You probably would want to process it in a controller into something easier to display in your template. Handlebars purposefully has as minimal logic as possible, so the heavy lifting should be done in a controller.

Comment: Well this object is the result of the serialisation of one of the model's properties. Ideally I could just reference the properties as `{{#each MyObject}} {{key}} = {{value}} {{/each}}` in a template.

Comment: I updated the question with a little more context about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why not mention `Ember.keys`?

Comment: Any insight to why `toString` is sometimes there?