# How to get all the properties from ember.js controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to get all the values from the controller that set using set() method.

For example : If

```
this.controllerFor('application').set("one", "1");
this.controllerFor('application').set("two", "2");
this.controllerFor('application').set("three", "3");
this.controllerFor('application').set("four", "4");
```

So How I can get all the values directly. I mean dont one by one using get() method.

Comment: May be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336461/iterating-through-an-ember-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `getProperties`, see an example

```
this.controllerFor('application').getProperties('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
```

Reference: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_getProperties

Comment: Hi Mateusz , Thanks for your time But Is there any way to get all the properties of controller with giving name inside the getProperties() method ?

Comment: Try `properties = Ember.keys(this.controllerFor('application'))` with `this.controllerFor('application').getProperties(properties)`